# Computing chlorophyll-a concentration with Sentinel 3 GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to compute chlorophyll-a concentration of the Tanganyika Lake with Sentinel 3. I'm facing an issue when trying : my results are constant values all over the study time.
Here is my code :

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI')
                  .filterDate('2017-10-17', '2018-03-16')
                  .filterBounds(geometry2);

// Select bands for visualization and apply band-specific scale factors.
var rgb = dataset.select(['Oa08_radiance', 'Oa06_radiance', 'Oa04_radiance'])
              .median()
              // Convert to radiance units.
              .multiply(ee.Image([0.00876539, 0.0123538, 0.0115198]));

var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 6,
  gamma: 1.5,
};

Map.setCenter(46.043, 1.45, 5);
Map.addLayer(rgb, visParams, 'RGB');

var dataset_mosaic = dataset.mosaic()
print(dataset)
//BRI
var chl_BRI = dataset_mosaic.expression(
  'B9/B11', {
    'B9': dataset_mosaic.select('Oa09_radiance'),
    'B11' : dataset_mosaic.select('Oa11_radiance')
  }).rename('BRI');
  
var BRI = dataset.map(
  function adddate (image){
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var dA = chl_BRI
  return dA.set('system:time_start', date);
});

var title_BRI = {
  title: 'Chlorophyll-a Concentration BRI',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'mg/m^3'},
};

var chart_BRI = ui.Chart.image.series
(BRI, geometry2, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setOptions(title_BRI)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print('Chlorophyll-a Concentration');
print(chart_BRI);
  
//NDCI
var chl_NDCI = dataset_mosaic.expression(
  '(B11-B9)/(B11+B9)', {
    'B9': dataset_mosaic.select('Oa09_radiance'),
    'B11' : dataset_mosaic.select('Oa11_radiance')
  }).rename('NDCI');
 
var NDCI = dataset.map(
  function adddate (image){
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var dA = chl_NDCI
  return dA.set('system:time_start', date);
});

var title_NDCI = {
  title: 'Chlorophyll-a Concentration NDCI',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'mg/m^3'},
};

var chart_NDCI = ui.Chart.image.series
(NDCI, geometry2, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setOptions(title_NDCI)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print('Chlorophyll-a Concentration');
print(chart_NDCI);

//NFHI
var chl_NFHI = dataset_mosaic.expression(
  'B10/B9', {
    'B9': dataset_mosaic.select('Oa09_radiance'),
    'B10' : dataset_mosaic.select('Oa10_radiance')
  }).rename('NFHI');
  
var NFHI = dataset.map(
  function adddate (image){
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var dA = chl_NFHI
  return dA.set('system:time_start', date);
});

var title_NFHI = {
  title: 'Chlorophyll-a Concentration NFHI',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'mg/m^3'},
};

var chart_NFHI = ui.Chart.image.series
(NFHI, geometry2, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setOptions(title_NFHI)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print('Chlorophyll-a Concentration');
print(chart_NFHI);

//TBI
var chl_TBI = dataset_mosaic.expression(
  '(1/B9-1/B11)*B12', {
    'B9': dataset_mosaic.select('Oa09_radiance'),
    'B11' : dataset_mosaic.select('Oa11_radiance'),
    'B12' : dataset_mosaic.select('Oa12_radiance')
  });
  
var TBI = dataset.map(
  function adddate (image){
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var dA = chl_TBI
  return dA.set('system:time_start', date);
});

var title_TBI = {
  title: 'Chlorophyll-a Concentration TBI',
  hAxis: {title: 'Time'},
  vAxis: {title: 'mg/m^3'},
};

var chart_TBI = ui.Chart.image.series
(TBI, geometry2, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30)
    .setOptions(title_TBI)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart');
print('Chlorophyll-a Concentration');
print(chart_TBI);

//Add layers
Map.addLayer(BRI, visParams, 'BRI');
Map.addLayer(NDCI, visParams, 'NDCI');
Map.addLayer(NFHI, visParams, 'NFHI');
Map.addLayer(TBI, visParams, 'TBI');
```

And here are the results I got :
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't do what you want it too:

```
var BRI = dataset.map(
  function adddate(image) {
    var date = image.get('system:time_start')
    var dA = chl_BRI
    return dA.set('system:time_start', date)
  }
)
```

You are mapping over `dataset`, but instead of calculating `BRI` for each image, you replace each image with the pre-calculated `chl_BRI`. You end up with a time-series with the same value. You are doing this with the other indexes too.

With out knowing the details, I'm guessing you want to do something like this:

```
var BRI = dataset.map(
  function (image) {
    var date = image.get('system:time_start')
    var dA = image.expression(
      'B9/B11', {
        'B9': image.select('Oa09_radiance'),
        'B11': image.select('Oa11_radiance')
      }).rename('BRI')
    return dA.set('system:time_start', date)
  }
)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e87bad9da7b1a42863141bae1c09705b

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's very helpfull. But now when I change the time_start and the time_end I have the following error : 
Error generating chart: Projection error: Unable to compute intersection of geometries in projections EPSG:32649: affine [246.95965156838372, 0.0, -131336.00551900768, 0.0, -246.95965156838372, 9649107.998250436] and EPSG:4326: affine [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0] (abstract projection)
Do you have any idea why ?